# Enforcing XML structure order in Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I'm currently trying to build a provisioning service of a kind for a local instance of Open-Xchange, using Rails 2.3.8, Savon and OX's SOAP API.

Via the console, I can issue the following commands that will work;

```
>> client = Savon::client("http://192.168.2.195/servlet/axis2/services/OXContextService?wsdl")
=> #<Savon::Client:0x2b5151bad790 @wsdl=#<Savon::Wasabi::Document:0x2b5151bad678 @document="http://192.168.2.195/servlet/axis2//services/OXContextService?wsdl", @request=#<HTTPI::Request:0x2b5151bad628>>, @http=#<HTTPI::Request:0x2b5151bad628>, @config=#<struct Savon::Config _logger=#<Savon::Logger:0x2b5151bad6c8 @device=#<IO:0x2b514a775ad0>>, pretty_print_xml=nil, raise_errors=true, soap_version=1, env_namespace=nil, soap_header=nil>>
>> client.request :list_by_database do
?> soap.body = {
?> :auth => {
?> :login => "oxadminmaster",
?> :password => "admin_master_password"
>> },
?> :db => {
?> :id => 3
>> }
>> }
>> end
HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the net_http adapter
SOAP request: https://192.168.2.195/servlet/axis2/services/OXContextService.OXContextServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/
SOAPAction: "urn:listByDatabase", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 657
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="http://soap.admin.openexchange.com" xmlns:ns="http://soap.admin.openexchange.com" xmlns:ins1="http://dataobjects.soap.admin.openexchange.com/xsd" xmlns:ins2="http://dataobjects.rmi.admin.openexchange.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><ins0:listByDatabase><ins0:db><ins1:id>3</ins1:id></ins0:db><ins0:auth><ins2:login>oxadminmaster</ins2:login><ins2:password>admin_master_password</ins2:password></ins0:auth></ins0:listByDatabase></env:Body></env:Envelope>
HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the net_http adapter
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
SOAP response (status 200):
```

It works, no problems there. However, when I try the following code...

```
class Ox_Context_Service
  extend Savon::Model

  attr_accessor :data, :returnCode

  document "http://192.168.2.195/servlet/axis2/services/OXContextService?wsdl"

  def list_by_database oxMasterUser, oxMasterPassword
    begin
    response = client.request :list_by_database do
      soap.body = {
        :auth => {
          #for the sake of testing
          :login => "#{oxMasterUser}",
          :password => "#{oxMasterPassword}"
        },
        :db => {
          :id => 3
          #For the sake of testing
        }
      }
      end
      if response.success?
        data = response.body[:list_by_database_response][:return]
        if data
          @data = data
          @returnCode = "#{response.http.code}"
        end
      end
    end
  rescue Savon::Error => fault
    @data = {}
    @returnCode = "#{fault}"
  end
end
```

Using the following CURL...

`curl localhost:4545/oxContextService/list_by_database -d 'oxUsername=oxadminmaster' -d 'oxPassword=admin_master_password'`

I get...

```
HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the net_http adapter
SOAP request: https://192.168.2.195/servlet/axis2/services/OXContextService.OXContextServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/
SOAPAction: "urn:listByDatabase", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 657
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="http://soap.admin.openexchange.com" xmlns:ns="http://soap.admin.openexchange.com" xmlns:ins1="http://dataobjects.soap.admin.openexchange.com/xsd" xmlns:ins2="http://dataobjects.rmi.admin.openexchange.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><ins0:listByDatabase><ins0:auth><ins2:login>oxadminmaster</ins2:login><ins2:password>admin_master_password</ins2:password></ins0:auth><ins0:db><ins1:id>3</ins1:id></ins0:db></ins0:listByDatabase></env:Body></env:Envelope>
HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the net_http adapter
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
SOAP response (status 500):
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Authentication failed</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

So- two identical calls, two different results. What could be going wrong here, SO?

Edit: The Rails call fails because the ***Auth*** block is sent first, instead of last. I think the new question is how to enforce XML structure order without explicitly writing out the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  soap.body = {
    :auth => {
      #for the sake of testing
      :login => "#{oxMasterUser}",
      :password => "#{oxMasterPassword}"
    },
    :db => {
      :id => 3
      #For the sake of testing
    }
    :order! => [:db, :auth]
 }
```

The `order!` will force a specific order based on that array. Lesson learned: Read the manual.